# One way access to devices on guest network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to configure a guest wireless network on the router asus RT-AC66U_B1. The network's purpose is to host iot devices and and a server running home automation software.

I'd like to be able to reach these devices from my main network to via protocols like SMB and SSH so i need to be able to see them, but at the same time i'd like them not to be able to see what's on the main network. The only setting i've found in the router is an "access intranet" checkbox on the guest network's settings, but that opens up everything so it kills the benefits of having a separate network.

Do you have any idea on how i might be able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, unfortunately none match all the criteria of secure, easy AND cheap.

1. If your Iot devices are all wireless you may be able to put them on a guest WIFI LAN (but im not  sure if the included firmware will allow the main LAN to reach the IOT lan - the servers may need to be hosted putside your network.
2. If you het a second router you can have the internet coming to the 'edge' router and connect yhe IOT devices to that. You then connect a LAN port on the edge router to the WAN port of the secind (core) router and hang your main network behind the core router. By using (double) NAT you effectively allow the Home router to reach the iot router and Internet but protect inbound connections. You just need to ensure the LAN ranges are different. (You could also drop NAT on the core router and replace it with routing and firewall rules, provided the core router csn do this.
3. The way I would do it would be to flash dd-wrt onto the router and then have 2 different LAN interfaces (it does not appear the supplied firmware can do this, but DD-WRT can. Once you have 2 lan segments set up you can use the router to route between them and firewall as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have a second router and i had exactly the 2nd configuration, but i wasnt able to ping the devices from the inner network..

Comment: @mrc Ok. Thats probably a seperate question - you would need to describe the network and hardware to find the problem.